# Optimize the performance of using HttpClient and TPL to validate proxies

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use HttpClient and TPL to validate some proxy addresses. I'm using something as simple as this and I've set `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;` before I start.

The problem I've found is that the result varies a lot between consecutive runs. Sometimes there can be 4 valid proxies and another run with one second after that will give you 194 valid proxies. I'm concerned that maybe I should handle task throttling. Is this something I should do by myself here?

Or are there any other issues I should try to handle?

```
internal class Validator
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, long> _validatedProxyDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, long>();
    private async Task<Tuple<bool, long>> ValidateProxy(Tuple<string, string, string> tuple)
    {
        try
        {
            string proxy = tuple.Item1;
            string url = tuple.Item2;
            string pattern = tuple.Item3;

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy, true),
                UseProxy = true
            };

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);

            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (str.Contains(pattern))
                _validatedProxyDic.TryAdd(proxy, stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            return new Tuple<bool, long>(str.Contains(pattern), stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return new Tuple<bool, long>(false, -1);
    }

    public void Foo(IEnumerable<string> proxyList, string loginUrl, string keyword)
    {
        var taskList = new List<Task<Tuple<bool, long>>>();
        foreach (var proxy in proxyList)
        {
            var tuple = new Tuple<string, string, string>(proxy, loginUrl, keyword);
            var task = Task.Run(() => ValidateProxy(tuple));
            taskList.Add(task);
        }
        var result = Task.WhenAll(taskList).Result;

        var validatedProxySortedList = from pair in _validatedProxyDic orderby pair.Value ascending select pair;

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("ProxyValidatedListSorted.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var proxy in validatedProxySortedList)
                sw.WriteLine(proxy.Key + "\t" + proxy.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Found {0} proxies.", validatedProxySortedList.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why, but it seems setting a small number of ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit (for example, 2) actually gives you more valid proxies.

Comment: `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` should have any effect only when you're making multiple requests to the same server (service point). Do you do that?

Comment: @svick: Yes I did. I have multiple threads using different proxy per thread to validate whether each proxy works. Then for each thread I get the page content of a particular Url and check if the returned stream contains a given keyword.

Comment: Ah, I should have read your code more carefully. Are all your proxies anonymous? If not, could it be that the target site is detecting this as a DoS attempt?

Comment: @svick: Yes. All my proxies are anonymous.